# Analysis Paralysis in looping over JSON data to populate select box with optgroup sections

Tags: javascript, json, coldfusion

I have [Analysis Paralysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis) and need some input. I can modify the SQL query, the JavaScript, AND/or the CFML controller (all code has been posted below).

All I'm looking to do is to populate a select box with options and optgroups. The optgroup is what is tripping me up here.

The sql is pretty basic and looks like this:

```
SELECT
    g.groupID,
    g.groupLabel,
    u.unitLabel,
    u.unitID
  FROM
    group g
    LEFT JOIN unit u ON g.groupID = u.groupID
```

And the CFML loop(s) is as follows (this is also where I believe the adjustment should be made with some logic such as if thisGroupLabel matches the preGroupLabel, stay within loop and keep adding unitLabel and unitIDs) but is there a more efficient way?:

```
local.data.unitLabels = [];
    for(local.row in local.__unitLabels){
        local.unit = {};
        local.unit.groupLabel = local.row.groupLabel;
        local.unit.unitLabel = local.row.unitLabel;
        local.unit.unitID = local.row.unitID;
        //  loop over the array so that we can identify which one needs to be preselected
        for(local.dataValue in local.data.unitDetails){
            if (local.unit.unitID eq local.dataValue.unitID) {
                local.unit.selected = 'selected';
            } else {
                local.unit.selected = '';
            }
        }
    arrayAppend(local.data.unitLabels, local.unit);
}
```

The JSON data looks like this but I have access to the query so I can reformat it if needed:

```
{
    "data": {
        "selectDataOptions": [{
            "groupLabel": "COMPLETION",
            "selected": "",
            "unitID": 1,
            "unitLabel": "Completion"
        }, {
            "groupLabel": "DISTANCE",
            "selected": "",
            "unitID": 2,
            "unitLabel": "Meters"
        }, {
            "groupLabel": "DISTANCE",
            "selected": "",
            "unitID": 3,
            "unitLabel": "Miles"
        }, {
            "groupLabel": "DISTANCE",
            "selected": "",
            "unitID": 4,
            "unitLabel": "Yards"
        }, {
            "groupLabel": "TIME",
            "selected": "",
            "unitID": 5,
            "unitLabel": "Hours"
        }, {
            "groupLabel": "TIME",
            "selected": "",
            "unitID": 5,
            "unitLabel": "minutes"
        }, {
            "groupLabel": "TIME",
            "selected": "",
            "unitID": 5,
            "unitLabel": "Seconds"
        }]
    }
}
```

As it stands, my select box looks like this (roughly):

```
<select>
    <optgroup>COMPLETION</optgroup>
    <option>Complettion</option>
    <optgroup>DISTANCE</OPTGROUP>
    <option>Meters</option>
    <optgroup>DISTANCE</optgroup>
    <option>Miles</option>
    <optgtroup>DISTANCE</optgroup>
    <option>Yards</option>
    <optgtroup>TIME</optgroup>
    <option>Hours</option>
    <optgtroup>TIME</optgroup>
    <option>Minutes</option>
</select>
```

Notice that the optgroup `Distance` and `TIME` are repeated. The desired output would look like this:

```
<select>
    <optgroup>COMPLETION</optgroup>
    <option>Complettion</option>
    <optgroup>DISTANCE</OPTGROUP>
    <option>Meters</option>
    <option>Miles</option>
    <option>Yards</option>
    <optgroup>TIME</optgroup>
    <option>Hours</option>
    <option>Mintues</option>
</select>
```

Comment: So the difficulty is in how to best construct the JSON representing the list options OR how to *use* that JSON on the front end to populate the lists? Also, not sure I follow how you're identifying which options should be pre-selected. Where does `local.dataValue.unitID`  come from? I only see it referenced in the code once..

Comment: The difficulty comment/question is correct. To respond to the other questions, the data will be populating a jQuery plugin, Select2, so that the options will be pre-selected for the user. The unitID will go into the `<option value=unitID>...</option>` but I left that out to keep the code more concise. I hope that didn't make it more confusing.

Comment: I just remembered a scoping issue using `FOR LOOPS` with ColdFusion so I'll probably need to change that to an `INDEX LOOP` instead.

Comment: Put a different way, is the issue how to construct a JSON string that Select2 can understand? I was going to suggest a nested array of children, as described under "Grouped Data" https://select2.org/data-sources/formats

Comment: What version of CF are you using? IIRC, CF11+ support cfloop "group", which would make it a lot easier...

Comment: Assuming the data is sorted by groupLabel first, here's an example (ignore the label differences) https://trycf.com/gist/9b0de6c843fbe3549128b1691fbafc27/acf11?theme=monokai

Comment: So sorry for the delay in getting back, stepped out for lunch. The element that contains the select box is being loaded after the DOM has been rendered so the Select2 has to be applied after the fact. All I need to do is construct the select box, apply the select2 plugin. Technically speaking, I'm using Lucee 5.x and it too does support cfloop with grouping.

Comment: Reviewing the gist...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180629/discussion-between-ageax-and-hpwd).

Comment: the gist you created helped tremendously. All I need to do now is modify my JS and I'm golden. The cfloop/group was a perfect solution.

Comment: If you'll move your GIST to an answer, I'll mark it as correct. The part I recycled was `data = [];
cfloop(query="qDemo", group="groupLabel") {
   children = [];
   cfloop() {
      arrayAppend(children, {"id": qDemo.unitID, "text": qDemo.unitLabel});
   }
   group = {"text" : qDemo.GroupLabel, "children" : children };
   arrayAppend(data, group);
}`

Comment: Great, glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the issue how to construct a JSON string that Select2 can understand? I'd suggest creating a nested array of children for each GroupLabel, as described in the documentation under [Grouped Data](http://select2.org/data-sources/formats).

CF11+ and Lucee 4.5+ support [cfloop "group"](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-j-l/cfloop-looping-over-a-query.html), which would make things a lot easier. Just cfloop through the query and group by "groupLabel". (*NB: Don't forget to modify the SQL query and `ORDER BY g.groupLabel` so the grouping works as expected.*)

[TryCF.com Example](https://trycf.com/gist/68f9d55b1eec8417cccbf3e0789b2a56/lucee5?theme=monokai)

**Code:**

```
data= [];
cfloop(query="qDemo", group="groupLabel") {

   children = [];
   cfloop() {
      arrayAppend(children, {"id": qDemo.unitID, "text": qDemo.unitLabel});
   }

   arrayAppend(data, {"text" : qDemo.GroupLabel, "children" : children });
}

writeDump(serializeJSON(data));
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "text": "COMPLETION",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "Completion",
        "id": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "DISTANCE",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "Meters",
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "text": "Miles",
        "id": 3
      },
      {
        "text": "Yards",
        "id": 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "TIME",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "Hours",
        "id": 5
      },
      {
        "text": "minutes",
        "id": 5
      },
      {
        "text": "Seconds",
        "id": 5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```